# Facing problem while getting Network & Security Logs for profile owner app

Tags: networking, content-security-policy, device-policy-manager, android-enterprise, profile-owner

The project I am working on is a Profile Owner Application.  I want to get the Network logs. I have successfully enabled the NetworkLogging and checked the Network logging enable status by setNetworkLoggingEnabled() and  isNetworkLoggingEnabled() methods.

Now I want to get the network logs using the retrieveNetworkLogs() method. which requires the parameter "batchToken : Long".

I have tried several ways to get the batchToken but have failed to get it. Now, I want your kind opinion on how to get the batchToken value and solve this problem by calling the retrieveNetworkLogs() method.

Thank you for your time.

val devicePolicyManager = getSystemService(Activity.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager?

//ComponentName is null because it is called by a delegated app.

devicePolicyManager?.setNetworkLoggingEnabled(null,true)
val isEnable = devicePolicyManager?.isNetworkLoggingEnabled(null)
val initialLogs = devicePolicyManager?.retrieveNetworkLogs(null, batchToken)

//need to know where to get this batchToken value

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the DelegateAdminReceiver class. Their you can get the batch token.

Android API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DelegatedAdminReceiver#onNetworkLogsAvailable(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent,%20long,%20int)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).